# Objective-C Preferences Window makeKeyAndOrderFront or showWindow?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm working on a new Mac App and want to open my Preferences Window, i've got 2 Nib (xib) Files, one for the main window, and one for the Preferences Window, then i've got a openPreferences Action, which shows the Preferences Window, sth. like this:

```
- (IBAction)openPreferences:(id)sender
{
    PrefCont *cont = [[PrefCont alloc] init];
    [cont showWindow:self];
}
```

this code works, but when i click more then once on the open Preferences Menu Item, then the Preferences Window opens twice or more then twice.

Is there a posibility to make it with sth. like makeKeyAndOrderFront but it must be called by the PrefController?

Or can i ask the Mac if the Window is opened? if not, then show it or sth. link this.

This would be very helpful, thanks to everbody!

Comment: Make sure you have turned off the "Visible at Launch" setting for your Window in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to avoid the double window symptom, you should make `PrefCont * cont` an ivar of this class, and then do:

```
- (IBAction) openPreferences:(id)sender {
  if (cont == nil) {
    cont = [[PrefCont alloc] init];
  }
  [cont showWindow:sender];
}
```

This way you'll only be creating one preference controller, and tell that one to show its window.

Don't forget to `[cont release];` when you're done...

Comment: thank you, this idea comes up to me yesterday night :D And its right, but thank you very much :)

Answer (score 5):

A better way would be to have the PrefCont class have a singleton routine like:

```
+(PrefCont*)prefs
{
  static PrefCont* prefs = nil;
  if (!prefs)
     prefs = [[PrefCont alloc] init];

  return prefs;
}
```

and then whenever you want to show the preferences, just call

```
  [[PrefCont prefs] showWindow:sender];
```